# How to pass `$(this)` to Slick.js plugin (and create multiple carousels with a loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

How do I pass `$(this).find('.option')` and `$(this).find('.prev_next')` to [Slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)? The following produces: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:not(.slick-cloned) in jquery-2.1.0.js:1429`

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/Lr30ngo1/4/

```js
$('.test').each(function () {
    var option = $(this).find('.option'),
        prev_next = $(this).find('.prev_next');

    $(this).slick({
        slide: option,
        appendArrows: prev_next,
        prevArrow: '<a>Previous</a>',
        nextArrow: '<a>Next</a>'
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Without something like this, Slick.js would freak out and produce a whole bunch of broken prev/next links: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/Lr30ngo1/3/

Here is the expected output with only one `.test` div: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/Lr30ngo1/6/

Comment: Looks like it should work. Where is the code mentioned it the error?

Comment: I don't know, all I see is a reference to `jquery-2.1.0.js:1429`.

Comment: It's still broken: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/Lr30ngo1/5 -- here's the expected output with only one `.test` div: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/Lr30ngo1/6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to pre-create the jQuery collections but instead just pass the selector strings as the values for the `slide` and `appendArrows`

You also need to uniquely identify the prev_next container and the options some how since slick wants a selector, and not an element/collection for those parameters.

**See the fixed jsFiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/2/

Fixed code follows: (this version uses your original markup, and dynamically assigns ID to each carousel to keep it "clean")

```js
$('.test').each(function (idx, item) {
   var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
   this.id = carouselId;
   $(this).slick({
       slide: "#" + carouselId +" .option",
       appendArrows: "#" + carouselId + " .prev_next",
       prevArrow: '<a>Previous</a>',
       nextArrow: '<a>Next</a>'
   });
});
```

```css
.prev_next a { display: inline-block; width:80px; text-align:center; margin: 2px; border: 0; padding: 4px; background-color: #666; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test">
<div class="prev_next"></div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
<div class="prev_next"></div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
<div class="prev_next"></div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But this way the prev/next links are all messed up. Please see expected output above.

Comment: Thanks again, but notice in my question I have 3 sliders, each with their own prev_next.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! However, I'm going to keep this question open a little bit longer hoping that maybe someone will come through with a slightly cleaner solution. Cheers!

Comment: Try it now: it is now cleaner (does not modify your original markup), but dynamically assigns `id` to each of the carousels, then uses that ID in the selectors to grab the correct options and prev_next containers.

Comment: Just came across this...you saved me in a real time crunch. Thank you!

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Thanks for providing this solution. Could you please be so kind in addition suggest how this method could be used with the Slider Syncing feature of the Slick.js. I would like to have multiple sliders but with navigation. I tried to play with the fiddle you shared but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Emil, that's a bit out of scope for this question, but if you post a new question about this I or somebody else will gladly take a look!