# Using More than One Slick Carousel on a Page

Tags: jquery

I am using Ken Wheeler's [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to add multiple sliders to a page. I am facing two issues:

1. The arrows are showing in each slide section and are not functioning properly.
2. The function used to show the current number of slides in each slide, changes on every slide section.

**HTML**

```
    <section id="project_01">
      <div class="slides slides-1 inner-wrap" data-offcanvas>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/team_designing.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
        <a href="#" class="left-off-canvas-toggle">
          <i class="scif-info22"></i>
          <i class="scif-times-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
     <div class="slide-nav">
      <div class="count"><span></span></div>        
      <div class="arrows"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section id="project_02">
      <div class="slides slides-2 inner-wrap" data-offcanvas>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
        <a href="#" class="left-off-canvas-toggle">
          <i class="scif-info22"></i>
          <i class="scif-times-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
     <div class="slide-nav">
      <div class="count"><span></span></div>        
      <div class="arrows"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section id="project_03">
      <div class="slides slides-3 inner-wrap" data-offcanvas>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
           <img src="img/9.jpg" alt="""">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
        <a href="#" class="left-off-canvas-toggle">
          <i class="scif-info22"></i>
          <i class="scif-times-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
     <div class="slide-nav">
      <div class="count"><span></span></div>        
      <div class="arrows"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
  var updateText = function (slick) {
    var $status = $('#project_01 .count > span'),
        text    = (slick.currentSlide + 1) + '/' + (slick.slideCount);
    $status.text(text);
  };
  //Slick slider
  $('.slides').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    appendArrows: $('.arrows'),
    arrows: true,
    autoplay: false,
    fade: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    onAfterChange: updateText,
    prevArrow: '<span class="slick-prev">Previous</span>',
    nextArrow: '<span class="slick-next">Next</span>',
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: true
      }
   }]
  });   
  updateText($('.slides').getSlick());
</script>
```

Of course I can repeat the jQuery and just change the IDs for each, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to simplify the code to get it to work properly. I want to be able to click the arrows in **each** slide section and it only update the slides in that section. Right now it's showing 3 sets of arrows and updates the slide number on each slide section. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: The answer to this question might help get you where you're looking to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491788/how-to-pass-this-to-slick-js-plugin-and-create-multiple-carousels-with-a-l